# shell_exec ffmpeg разрешение видео

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Мне нужно получить ширину и высоту видео с помощью ffmpeg через shell_exec. Какую команду мне нужно для этого использовать?

Comment: ffprobe - часть пакета ffmpeg, ищите что-то типа http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co/11236144#11236144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете *ffmpeg*, команда такая:

```
ffmpeg -i видеофайл
```

Она выводит много строк, интересны строки, описывающие видео и аудио:

```
 Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9838 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
 Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
```

Где размер видео - `1920x1080`, что в данном случае соответствует *1080p* или *FullHD*